# jQuery click() event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of an issue with this code I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#continue" ).click(function() {
            var c = $('[name="recaptcha_challenge_field"]').attr('name');
            var r = $('[name="recaptcha_response_field"]').attr('name');
            alert( "c=" + c );
            alert( "r=" + r );
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Alert box would not show up when the button with id `continue` is clicked. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you show the HTML and make a jsFiddle?

Comment: You have a syntax error. Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) to see the errors.

Comment: Some html would be more helpful.  However, if #continue is added to the DOM after the JS has been loaded, you will need to delegate the event with `$("body").on("click", "#continue", function()`

Comment: oh, too many down votes :-/

Comment: just use `<script>` (not the answer)

Comment: @Juhana I think that typo was made by the OP while he was pasting the code here.. let's re-open this...

Comment: I voted to keep closed as "debug my code for me", as it currently stands.  We are happy to help with specific errors or problems.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Still not reason enough to reopen; nothing wrong with the code that's now in the question, so the problem is in a code (or HTML) the OP isn't showing us. Fails the "shortest program **necessary**" requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a clossing `})`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#continue" ).click(function() {
        var c = $('[name="recaptcha_challenge_field"]').attr('name');
        var r = $('[name="recaptcha_response_field"]').attr('name');
        alert( "c=" + c );
        alert( "r=" + r );
    });
}); // <<<<<==== THIS IS MISSING
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a closing function wrapper for document ready. So it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#continue" ).click(function() {
        var c = $('[name="recaptcha_challenge_field"]').attr('name');
        var r = $('[name="recaptcha_response_field"]').attr('name');
        alert( "c=" + c );
        alert( "r=" + r );
    });
});
```